# Storing and retrieving messages in Openfire server according to thread id

Tags: xmpp, openfire

We are implementing a chat application using Openfire as server. The clients are various mobile platform and web interface for which we are using xmppframework for iOS Smack for Android and Strophe.js for the web.

Following this http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html#bizrules-threads we are sending messages with different thread values to start a new thread. But we noticed that while archiving through the Monitor plugin available for Openfire the details like thread is not stored. In server the auto archive mode is on.

As mentioned here the manual archive is not yet implemented in this plugin http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html

Was anybody successful to store the messages according to thread ids in Openfire and also retrieve that information while showing the chat history on the clients ?